# Is it haram to make predictions when you are pretty sure it's not gonna happen?

Tags: halal-haram, kufr, sports

Assalamualaikum, i actually yesterday was watching a basketball match, some of my friends just made a prediction of which teach will win and just try to predict score and they were totally sure that its probably not gonna happen like they weren't completely sure that prediction is gonnw come true. And also is making prediction based on some things you observe in environment or studying it or by seeing a team's past matches and their playing form haram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two points where this may be similar to haram action:

- Gambling as betting for money or similar is haram.
- Soothsaying or pretending to know the future is haram.

We need to make assumptions on our future every day, based on experience even if it is just a certain probability. This applies to all probability forecast. An example for halal forecast: weather [forecast](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/muftionline/104674/checking-the-weather-forecast/)  Such kind of forecast is halal.

It's halal if you sit together with friends before a match and exchange your guess (without any agreement that if someone is right he would get something, which would be gambling), not pretending to really know (which would be foretelling)